# On AWS Elastic Beanstalk, how can I keep instances ready but not serving until the main instance crashes?

Tags: go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm working on an app that currently cannot work correctly if it is run as multiple instances behind a load balancer that sends traffic to more than one instance. That is because the web sockets are coordinated via goroutines rather than via an external pub/sub system. Also, the app crashes sometimes, and it takes about 30s for it to come back up, so I would like to have another instance of it ready to serve when the live instance crashes.

Is there a good way to do that within Elastic Beanstalk, minimizing downtime?

Comment: I know of no great way.  You could have other instances fail their health checks until the main instance is sick, but you'd need leader election to decide which instance takes over.  You could proxy requests from non-leader instances to the leader, but you'd still need leader election.  I would recommend you make the app work correctly with multiple instances.

Comment: You have to fully re-architect your application. EB does not have such ability.

Comment: Use elasticache with redis's streams feature,  maybe.